# Why is it a good practise to create a new instance of Stream per each I/O operation? (C#)

Tags: c#, ssh, streaming

There is a lot of examples of code when one uses the following construction of implementation I/O operations with Stream class. Like this:

```
void ReadFileBro()
{
    using(var fs = File.Open("file.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
         using(var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
         {
              //read file
         }
    }
}
```

When we call ReadFileBro it always creates new istances of Stream-concrete implemetations. Once the operation is repeat it destroys ones.

Why can I not just create my StreamReader once and save it as property of any class for multiply using?

Recently I've deployed a small app for client-server interaction through SSH (using [SSH.NET][1]). This (simplified)code worked wrong:

```
class MyConnection
{
    ShellStream myStream = client.CreateShellStream(...);//it represents Stream between client and server, create it as single instance for each calling SendCommand

    void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        myStream.WriteLine(command);//send a command to server
        string readed = null;
        while (myStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            output = myStream.Read();//get data from server
        }
    }
}
```

However this code works good:

```
class MyConnection
{
    void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        myStream.WriteLine(command);
        using(var myStream = client.client.CreateShellStream(...))
        { /* get data from server */ }
    }
}
```

How could this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary reason that you close a stream after usage and create a new one is due to the locking of the resources and freeing the resources on the actual resource.  Typically speaking, keeping an `IDisposable` object for a long time is a bad practice.

The cost of creating a new object is very low, and ensures proper resource management.

**Edit:** In the case of your specific situation, your way most likely works, however, you should properly implement IDisposable.  Below is a high-level example

```
class MyConnection : IDisposable
{
    ShellStream myStream = client.CreateShellStream(...);//it represents Stream between client and server, create it as single instance for each calling SendCommand

    void SendCommand(string command)
    {
        myStream.WriteLine(command);//send a command to server
        string readed = null;
        while (myStream.DataAvailable)
        {
            output = myStream.Read();//get data from server
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()  
    {  
        Dispose(true);  
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);  
    } 

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)  
    {  
        if (disposing)   
        {  
            // free managed resources  
            if myStream != null)  
            {  
                myStream .Dispose();  
                myStream = null;  
            }  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: There is ShellStream class in SSH.NET library (client-server changing data). This class has a property represents event which fires when a new  message has come. if Dispose() of instance of ShellStream is called then my handlers can't subscribe on this event. Can I saves ShellStream instance at this scenario?

Comment: ShellStream is a different implementation than the more general stream.  In your case, the implementation option could outline another option.  However, I would strongly recommend if you are holding it, you should also implement IDisposable yourself

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is recommended that you initialize a stream and close it per request for two reasons:

1. You ensure that you open and close each stream.
2. You don't have many streams open which can cause issues. This is common with database connections.

Answer (score 0):

`Using` is short hand for creating a disposable object then allowing operations to run on the object. When it exits the using block the object runs it's `Dispose()` method.

`IDisposable` is important for objects that either use external resources, such as files, databases etc and it's extremely important where the object in question accesses unmanaged code. Your filestream object no doubt accesses lower level system components to access files and read/write to them. The filestream implements `IDisposable` because it's `Dispose()` method will run private methods to close down any resources that it has been accessing. This is to help prevent memory leaks, locked resources and suchlike.

An object that does not implement `IDisposable` is normally invalidated when the object in question moves out of scope, that is to say, the code execution has moved to another method where it can no longer access the object instance. After a short time these types of objects are marked as invalid by the Garbage Collector and cleaned up automatically, so long as there are no active pointers to that object.

IDisposable is different because we are accessing external resources that the GC has no access to, yet still occupy the application memory. Dispose() methods ensure this all tidied up manually. It's like cleaning your own table after you've eaten instead of getting a waiter to do it.

Comment: What about a scenario when Stream implementation has any events (for example, now new data have come)? I can not subscribe on these if Dispose() is called for Stream

Comment: You'd store that separately and raise the event after you're done with the stream